# Adding an Ubuntu client to a Windows Server 2008 domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, ubuntu, domain

I have a Windows Server 2008 virtual machine that has its domain. I want to create ANOTHER virtual machine with Ubuntu 9.10 beta and have it connect as a client.

Is there a guide or tutorial I can follow related to this?

Any help is appreciated. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good how to [here](http://www.onnoot.com/wiki/how_to_join_ubuntu_samba_to_a_windows_2003_active_directory_domain) on Join Ubuntu to a Windows 2003 domain, using Samba. The principal is the same for joining a 2008 domain.